# Edit Screen Graphics

Tags: .net, user-interface, graphics, monitor

Is there away to directly edit what is on the screen? Not making a window, but intercepting what is going to be displayed and editing it, before passing it on to the monitor? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To put it briefly : **No**, there is not any easy way to do that.

I'm assuming, that you're talking about Windows, but this would apply to many other operating systems like Linux or MacOS.

---

At some address on your computer there is a so-called [framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer), which stores all of the pixel colors to then display on your screen. I don't know the exact location of it in memory, maybe something like 0x400000, but that's besides the point, because you can't access it anyway. Some parts of memory is reserved for the operating system and **cannot** be accessed by other user space processes.

If you really want to access the raw framebuffer pixels, you can implement your own drivers (not recommended), or you can make your own operating system (definitely not recommended).

The lowest you can get with framebuffers is probably with [OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL), which provides you with a lot of low-level graphics function as well as the ability to create your own framebuffers (though such framebuffer would still have be drawn to a default framebuffer and passed through Windows *Window-like* system.

---

**So, the conclusion is** : There is no way to access the screen pixels without a whole lot of work.